# Left Outer Join Does not preserve Left Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, left-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT Q_ID,
   Q_DESC,
   COUNT(Q_ID)
FROM   #tmp_rep
   LEFT OUTER JOIN po_Questions po
        ON  Q_ID = Certificate AND FUNCS = 1
        AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(po.UserName))) > 0
        AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(po.UserNumber))) > 0
GROUP BY
   Q_ID,
   Q_DESC
ORDER BY
   Q_ID
```

---

the table #tmp_rep has 2 columns(Q_ID,Q_Desc) and 4 rows.and table po_Questions has 10 that **use 3 Q_ID code in column Certificate** rows. If I run this query every thing is ok and for Q-ID=4 I get 0 for count,but If I wrote that query this way:

```
SELECT Q_ID,
   Q_DESC,
   COUNT(Q_ID)
FROM   #tmp_rep
   LEFT OUTER JOIN po_Questions po
        ON  Q_ID = Certificate 
WHERE FUNCS = 1
      AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(po.UserName))) > 0
        AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(po.UserNumber))) > 0

GROUP BY
   Q_ID,
   Q_DESC
ORDER BY
   Q_ID
```

then I get just 3 rows in the result and Q_ID=4 does not belong to result.Why SQL Server has this behaivior?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the non matching rows `po.UserName` will be `NULL` so `LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(po.UserName)))` is `NULL`

`NULL > 0` evaluates to `UNKNOWN` not `TRUE` so when the predicate is in the `WHERE` you are turning your outer join back into an inner one. Similarly for `FUNCS` as SQLMenace points out.

You might want to Download [Itzik Ben Gan's Logical Query Processing poster](http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf).

**Conceptually** the following happens (this should not be confused with how it is **physically** implemented however!)

For your first query:

- Cartesian Product on `#tmp_rep`, `po_Questions`
- Then the `ON Filter` is applied which effectively does an `INNER JOIN` on `Q_ID = Certificate` but also excludes any `po_Questions` rows that don't match your predicate.
- Then the non matching `Outer` Rows from `#tmp_rep` are added back in. These will have `NULL` for all columns from  `po_Questions`
- There is no `WHERE` clause so this is the final result.

For your second query:

- Cartesian Product on `#tmp_rep`, `po_Questions`
- Then the `ON Filter` is applied which effectively does an `INNER JOIN` on `Q_ID = Certificate`.
- Then the non matching `Outer` Rows from `#tmp_rep` are added back in. These will have `NULL` for all columns from  `po_Questions`
- Then the `WHERE` clause is evaluated. This will definitely remove all rows from the previous step and possibly additional rows too.

Comment: Nice..I knew about the order but didn't know Itzik had it in poster form..thanks

Comment: Sorry Dear @Martin Smith:I read in a web site that in LEFT JOIN the result record number equals to left table record number.I say if It can't evaluate WHERE predicate it return an exception or null for count.

Comment: @Nima: In short, what you've read about joins *is* true, but that applies to *joins alone*. Logically, the WHERE clause is evaluated *after* the joins, thus additional rows may get filtered out.

Comment: Note that Itzik's info has been queried http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/10/sql-server-download-logical-query-processing-poster/

Comment: @gbn - Well `TOP ... ORDER BY` is a bit weird as the `ORDER BY` both defines the `TOP` and the order of results, looks like Itzik did change his mind himself [between versions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270338/confused-about-itzik-ben-gans-logical-query-processing-order-in-his-sql-server-2) there are other anomalies too like you can `ORDER BY` something not in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: MSDN has it for SQL Server 2008 but not for '2005 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx which shows correctly (IMO).

Answer (score 2):

In essence you have created an inner join, change

```
WHERE FUNCS = 1
```

to

```
AND FUNCS = 1
```

The left outer joined cannot be specified in the WHERE clause otherwise it will be filtered out

another problem is the LEN function on NULLs it won't be greater than 0

Comment: Thanks for the link...I forgot it was there