# MYSQL query where I want to filter one specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to filter, so the column `salaryMonth` only contains data which has `2020` inside, so `2019` is filtering out.

```
SELECT sum(km_amount) as total
     , user_id
     , salaryMonth 
  from kms
     , users 
 where users.id = kms.user_id 
 group 
    by salaryMonth
     , user_id
```

[image]

Comment: where `YEAR(salaryMonth) = YEAR(NOW())` this is for current year, and if you want to define which year then its like `YEAR(salaryMonth) = 2018`

Comment: field salaryMonth is which type ???

Comment: And consider revising your schema

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `JOIN`, `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```sql
SELECT
    sum(km_amount) as total, 
    user_id, 
    salaryMonth 
FROM kms, users 
WHERE
    users.id=kms.user_id 
    AND salaryMonth LIKE '%2020%' 
GROUP BY 
    salaryMonth, user_id
```

Comment: Note that we stopped writing queries this way ca 1992

Comment: @Strawberry could you clarify what is wrong with this way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581774/can-someone-help-explain-why-not-using-a-sql-join-is-bad-practice-and-wrong/8582168#8582168

Comment: I mean, why post a snarky comment and not just be helpful in the first place?

Comment: @DmitriyH . . . To be specific, it is rather shocking that anyone would provide an answer using commas in the `FROM` clause rather than proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: yes, thanks for the clarification. My first thought was that 'like' using is a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You could save yourself no end of misery be refactoring your table as:

```
total user_id salary_yearmonth
  625      64 2020-02-01 
  595      70 2020-02-01 
  600      74 2020-02-01
  632      75 2020-02-01
  471      77 2020-02-01
  788      29 2019-03-01
   35       4 2020-03-01
   22      39 2020-03-01
  373      47 2020-03-01
  196      53 2020-03-01
  140      74 2020-03-01
  228      75 2020-03-01
   49      29 2019-04-01 
   96      63 2019-05-01 
  406       4 2019-06-01 
  966       4 2019-07-01 
  514       1 2019-08-01 
  637       4 2019-08-01
  580      47 2019-08-01
   11       1 2019-09-01
```

Comment: Actually the salaryMonth column is a string but in the same table I have a date field for same purpose, so I could filter it from there as well. Your right :)