# SQL invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting an error "invalid column name 'FirstPart'" when I do a left join.

I know my column is an alias, but I am not sure what to do:

```
SELECT
    h.Type,
    a.name,
    CASE 
       WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' 
          THEN LEFT(a.name, CHARINDEX('-', a.name) - 1) 
          ELSE a.name 
    END as FirstPart,
    CASE 
       WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' 
          THEN RIGHT(a.name, CHARINDEX('-', Reverse(a.v)) - 1) 
    END as LastPart
FROM 
    Table1 a
LEFT JOIN
    Table2 h ON a.FirstPart = h.ID
```

Comment: Either repeat the expression or pull it in a sub-query

Comment: If you understand the t-sql logical processing order ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270338/confused-about-itzik-ben-gans-logical-query-processing-order-in-his-sql-server), you will understand why you have the problem in the first place, i.e. you cannot use alias (in SELECT clause) in the FROM clause (which contains JOINs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your alias would be available if you wrapped this whole thing in an outer query, but since you're on the same level as the alias, you need to derive it again with the same logic:

```
Select  

  h.Type,
  a.name,
  CASE 
    WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' THEN LEFT(a.name, Charindex('-', a.name) - 1) 
    ELSE a.name
  END as FirstPart,
  CASE
    WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' THEN RIGHT(a.name, Charindex('-', Reverse(a.v)) - 1)
  END as LastPart
from Table1 a
  left join Table2 h 
    on CASE WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' THEN LEFT(a.name, Charindex('-', a.name) - 1) ELSE a.name END = h.ID
```

If you wrapped this, you could reference by subquery:

```
select * 
from 
 (Select h.Type, a.name,
  CASE WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' THEN LEFT(a.name, Charindex('-', a.name) - 1) ELSE a.name END as FirstPart,
  CASE WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' THEN RIGHT(a.name, Charindex('-', Reverse(a.v)) - 1) END as LastPart
  from Table1 a ) inn
left join Table2 h 
  on inn.FirstPart = h.ID
```

As a side note, if you can avoid the join on a `like` match, you'll get better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-query to use the alias

```
SELECT h.type, 
       a.name,
       a.firstpart,
       a.lastpart
  FROM (SELECT name,
               CASE WHEN name LIKE '%-%' 
                    THEN LEFT(name, CHARINDEX('-', name) - 1) 
                    ELSE name 
                END AS firstpart,
               CASE WHEN name LIKE '%-%' 
                    THEN RIGHT(name, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(v)) - 1) 
                END AS lastpart
          FROM table1
        ) a
   LEFT JOIN table2 h 
     ON a.firstpart = h.id
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server offers fourth option (after repeating the expression, using subqueries, or using CTEs) . . . `apply`.  This is nice, because you can "nest" expressions without having to indent the code more and more:

```
Select h.Type, a.name, FirstPart, LastPart
from Table1 a cross apply
     (values (CASE WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' THEN LEFT(a.name, Charindex('-', a.name) - 1) ELSE a.name END,
              CASE WHEN a.name LIKE '%-%' THEN RIGHT(a.name, Charindex('-', Reverse(a.v)) - 1) END)
     ) v(First_part, LastPart) left join
     Table2 h
     on v.FirstPart = h.ID;
```