# RANK OVER PARTITION BY on aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

Here is a set of 3 tables:

**Orders** `(ORDER_ID, CUSTOMER_ID, ORDER_DATE)`

**Order detail** `(ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, PRICE, UNITS)`

**Customers** `(CUSTOMER_ID, SIGNUP_DATE, COUNTRY)`

I need to identify the top 3 months, by revenue, for each country.
This is the query that I thought of:

```
SELECT c.country
    , MONTH(o.order_date) as _Month
    , SUM(od.price * od.units) AS revenue
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country, _Month ORDER BY revenue) AS Rank  
FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN customers c ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id  
JOIN order_detail od 
WHERE o.order_id = od.order_id GROUP BY country, Month
HAVING Rank <= 3
```

Will this query work because I am not sure if `SUM(od.price * od.units) as revenue` can be used in the RANK() OVER function or not since it's an aggregate function?

Comment: What database are you using?  Only MySQL 8.0 supports window functions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunately I do not have a database setup but I was practicing MySQL.

Comment: Are you sorting by the top 3 months of revenue for each country, or top 3 countries' revenue for each month?

Comment: @Shawn I am sorting by the top 3 months of revenue for each country

Comment: And do you have any sample data that you're working with?

Comment: I am sorry. Unfortunately, I do not have any data. I was just practicing some SQL queries and had this doubt of RANK() and aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In databases that support window functions, this would normally be written as:

```
SELECT cm.*
FROM (SELECT c.country, MONTH(o.order_date) as Month, SUM(od.price * od.units) AS revenue,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country, MONTH(o.order_date) ORDER BY SUM(od.price * od.units) ) AS Rank 
      FROM orders o LEFT JOIN
           customers c
           ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id  JOIN
           order_detail od 
           ON o.order_id = od.order_id
      GROUP BY country, Month
     ) cm
HAVING Rank <= 3;
```

Comment: will it work if I just write `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country, Month ORDER BY revenue ) AS Rank`

Comment: @DigvijaySawant . . . Not in most databases, unless you have a column in one of the tables called `month`.

Comment: Got it. So alias names do no work in RANK() function but they are fine in group by.. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Not quite. Alias do work in analytical functions but, like in most places, not at at he same level as they're being created.     select ...
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country, _Month ORDER BY revenue) AS Rank 
      from (select ...
                 , MONTH(o.order_date) as _Month
                 , SUM(od.price * od.units) AS revenue,  
             ... 
           )

Comment: @GordonLinoff Doesn't `GROUP BY country, Month` need to be `GROUP BY country, MONTH(o.order_date)` since the `Month` alias won't be available to the `GROUP BY`? And instead of `HAVING Rank <= 3`, should it be `WHERE Rank <= 3` since there's no grouping in the outer select? Not sure if that's a MySQL syntax or not.

Answer (score 2):

This is meant to be more Comment than Answer, since I can format a bit prettier down here, but the typical query logical order of operations goes something along the lines of:

`FROM` is built first.
  `JOIN`s will be applied.
`WHERE` will cause the above tables to be filtered
`GROUP BY` and `aggregates` will be applied.
`HAVING` is applied.
`WINDOW FUNCTION`s will be calculated. These operate outside of the `ORDER BY`
`SELECT` will be applied.
`DISTINCT` will be applied.
`ORDER BY` will be applied.
`TOP`/`LIMIT` will be applied.

In general, anything that happens in a step will be available to the steps following it (ie a `SELECT` alias can be used in the `ORDER BY` but not in the `GROUP BY`. But in MySQL, the `HAVING` can use aliases defined in the `SELECT`. Of course, the optimizer can always decide to do its own thing and may choose a different order, but this is what usually happens in most flavors of SQL.

A couple of references I have are MS SQL related, but, for the most part, still apply to other types:

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/10/10/sql-server-download-logical-query-processing-poster/

[Confused about Itzik Ben-Gan's Logical Query Processing order in his SQL Server 2005 book and SQL Server 2008 book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270338/confused-about-itzik-ben-gans-logical-query-processing-order-in-his-sql-server)

https://accessexperts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Logical-Query-Processing-Poster.pdf

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/logical-query-processing/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Gordon Linoff's answer is right.

(1) You can not directly call the alias in the Rank() function, which has been mentioned by Gordon

(2) For your use case, you want to rank the months within each country, the rank part should be

```
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY SUM(od.price * od.units) ) AS Rank
```