# SQL Fieldname vs Aliasname

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have been trying to figure out why the following SQL works

```
SELECT c_Supplier.Supplier_ID AS A_ID, c_Supplier.Name, c_Supplier.RFC, c_Supplier_Direccion.Description, c_Supplier_Direccion.Address, c_Supplier_Phone.Phone
FROM c_Supplier LEFT JOIN (c_Supplier_Direccion LEFT JOIN c_Supplier_Phone ON c_Supplier_Direccion.Supplier_Direccion_ID = c_Supplier_Phone.Supplier_Direccion_ID) ON c_Supplier.Supplier_ID = c_Supplier_Direccion.Supplier_ID
WHERE (c_Supplier.Supplier_ID=1);
```

But when I try to use the aliasname (`A_ID`) in the `WHERE` clause, I got an error

```
SELECT c_Supplier.Supplier_ID AS A_ID, c_Supplier.Name, c_Supplier.RFC, c_Supplier_Direccion.Description, c_Supplier_Direccion.Address, c_Supplier_Phone.Phone
FROM c_Supplier LEFT JOIN (c_Supplier_Direccion LEFT JOIN c_Supplier_Phone ON c_Supplier_Direccion.Supplier_Direccion_ID = c_Supplier_Phone.Supplier_Direccion_ID) ON c_Supplier.Supplier_ID = c_Supplier_Direccion.Supplier_ID
WHERE (A_ID=1);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: _Column_ name, not field name...

Comment: [Logical query processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270338/confused-about-itzik-ben-gans-logical-query-processing-order-in-his-sql-server) `WHERE` is before `SELECT`. The point is the way something is written is not the same as it is executed.

Comment: Yeah, I meant c_Supplier.Supplier_ID when refering to fieldname and A_ID when referring to Aliasname. I thought column name may be confusing since the query column name comes as the aliasname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question.  This is a reasonably formed SQL query:

```
SELECT c_Supplier.Supplier_ID AS Entidad_ID, c_Supplier.Name,
       c_Supplier.RFC, c_Supplier_Direccion.Description,
       c_Supplier_Direccion.Address, c_Supplier_Phone.Phone
FROM c_Supplier LEFT JOIN
     (c_Supplier_Direccion LEFT JOIN
      c_Supplier_Phone
      ON c_Supplier_Direccion.Supplier_Direccion_ID = c_Supplier_Phone.Supplier_Direccion_ID
     ) ON c_Supplier.Supplier_ID = c_Supplier_Direccion.Supplier_ID
WHERE (c_Supplier.Supplier_ID = 1);
```

(I would recommend table aliases for readability, but that is a separate issue.)

It has no alias called `A_ID` anywhere in the query, so there is no reason to ever expect a reference to `A_ID` to work (unless it is a column in one of the tables).

And, SQL doesn't allow the re-use of table aliases in the `SELECT` where they are defined or the `WHERE` clause.  This is not an MS Access limitation; it is how the SQL language is defined.

If you want to do so in MS Access, you can use a subquery and reference the table alias in the outer query.

Comment: Sorry, while translating the code to English I forgot to change `SELECT c_Supplier.Supplier_ID AS Entidad_ID` to `SELECT c_Supplier.Supplier_ID AS A_ID`

Comment: The question is ... I SELECT c_Supplier.Supplier_ID AS A_ID, why does it recognize WHERE c_Supplier.Supplier_ID=1 but it does not recognize WHERE A_ID=1

Comment: @DrYunke . . . The last two paragraphs answer your question.  You cannot re-use aliases like that.  You would need to use a subquery.